# Install Check Script that checks Profiles -P for a specific profile

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, mdm, profiles

I am trying to write up a instal check script that runs `profiles -P`and exits based on the response.

We use a profile from meraki which the output looks like so (if installed):

```
_computerlevel[1] attribute: profileIdentifier: com.meraki.sm.mdm
There are 1 configuration profiles installed
```

Is there a way to check this out put for this exact response?

I was thinking something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=profiles -P
if [ output = com.meraki.sm.mdm ]; then
exit 0;
else
exit 1;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if sudo profiles -P | egrep -q ': com.meraki.sm.mdm$'; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

- Output from `sudo profiles -P` (note that `profiles` always requires root privileges) is sent via a pipe (`|`) to `egrep`; the two commands form a *pipeline*.
- `egrep -q ': com.meraki.sm.mdm$'` searches through `profile`'s output:

  - `-q` (quiet) option produces no output and simply signals via its exit code whether a match was found (`0`) or not (`1`).
  - `': com.meraki.sm.mdm$'` is a regular expression that matches string 'com.meraki.sm.mdm' found at the end of the line (`$`), preceded by ': '.
  - `(`egrep`is the same as`grep -E` - it activates support for *extended* regular expressions - not strictly necessary here, but generally advisable for fewer surprises).
- The `if` statement *evaluates to true if the pipeline returns exit code `0`*, and to false otherwise (nonzero). Note that by default it is the *last* command in the pipeline whose exit code determines the pipeline's overall exit code.

---

Incidentally, if all you wanted to do is to have your script reflect whether the string was found or not (i.e., if you don't need to take further action inside your script), the following would suffice:

```
sudo profiles -P | egrep -q ': com.meraki.sm.mdm$'
exit $?   # Special variable `$?` contains the most recent command's exit code
```

If you wanted to exit your script right after in the event of *failure* only:

```
sudo profiles -P | egrep -q ': com.meraki.sm.mdm$' || exit

# Alternative, with error message:
sudo profiles -P | egrep -q ': com.meraki.sm.mdm$' ||
  { ec=$?; echo 'Profile not installed.' >&2; exit $ec; }
```

Conversely, if you wanted to exit right after in the event of *success*:

```
sudo profiles -P | egrep -q ': com.meraki.sm.mdm$' && exit
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This will work our perfectly. I will have to swap the Exit code's for the purpose I'm using it for, but it's perfect. Thanks! Now to fix the Curl issue  >:D

Comment: @WardsParadox: Glad to hear it's working for you; my pleasure.

Comment: Just a quicky, but if it's being used in an installer situation, does it still need the sudo? Since installers prompt (well all of mine that I build) need administrative privileges for root permissions, than it shouldn't need sudo, correct?

Comment: @WardsParadox: Yes, if the script is truly running as root, you do not need `sudo` - but it'll also work if you leave the `sudo` prefix in. If you want an explicit check for admin (root) privileges in a script, use `[[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]] || { echo 'This script must be run as root.' >&2; exit 1; }`